# WinForms DataGridView - Edit user input before writing to DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, timezone

I am creating an application for logging employee time.  All time data for all users will be stored in a SQL database, in UTC.  The front-end will be a Windows Forms app that displays time and accepts input in the local time zone of the user.  The WinForms app has a `DataGridView` control which is where time will be both displayed and input by users.

The `DataGridView` is bound to a `List` of `TimeSegment` objects. `TimeSegment` is a struct I created which is basically this:

```
struct TimeSegment 
{

    private DateTime start, end;

    public TimeSegment(DateTime start, DateTime end){
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public DateTime Start 
    {
        get { return start; } 
        set {
            if (value.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc)
                throw new ArgumentException("Only UTC dates are allowed.");
            start = value;
        }
    }

    //There is an End property which is just like the Start 
    //property, but for the 'end' field.
}
```

So in the `DataGridView`, there will be a column of start times and a column of end times, with each row representing some event or task a user performed.

I know how to convert the internal UTC time to the local timezone for display by using the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event. The problem I am having is with taking user input in local time and converting to UTC before sending the update to the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`.

I've seen several other posts showing how to change the text in the cell on `DataGridView`'s `CellParsing` or `CellValidating` events, but I need to change the actual object that the text gets parsed as, that gets sent to the `DataSource`.

Is there a way to override the parsing behavior of the cell and specify what object should get sent to the DataSource?

Comment: why can't you do the editing of the data in the `OnBound` Event of the DataGridView.. ?

Comment: Isn't the [DataGridView.CellParsing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing(v=vs.110).aspx) event exactly for that? Even the sample in the documentation shows conversion to UTC.

Comment: @ MethodMan - I don't see any DataGridView.OnBound event. / @ Ivan - Thanks, I actually just revisited that page before checking back in here.  I think that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
private void mainGrid_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Convert time
    (mainGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as TimeSegment).Start = convertedValue;
}
```